# How to make short URL using .htaccess - vbulletin forum

Tags: .htaccess, vbulletin

i have a vbulletin forum
i want to make short url like this
`http://nusa.in/t1791` will redirect to http://www.nusareborn.in/showthread.php?t=1791

ex:

```
short domain : short.domain.com
my forum domain : forum.domain.com
```

how to do that? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the htaccess file in your `nusa.in` document root:

```
RedirectMatch ^/t([0-9]+)$ http://www.nusareborn.in/showthread.php?t=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Redirect 301 http://www.mysite.com/about_us.php http://www.mysite.com/about-us/
Redirect 301 http://www.mysite.com/contacts.php http://www.mysite.com/contacts/
```

use above code in htaccess